# Alternatives to creating and iterating through a list for "bad" values each time clean is called in django?

Tags: python, sql, database, django, web

Let's say I have a group of words that I don't want to allow my users to include in their titles that they are going to be submitting. What are some alternatives on how to store those values besides hardcoding the list into the clean function?

I thought about creating a new model that would contain all of these words that aren't allowed but I am not sure whether or not querying the database each time clean was called for that function would be slower/faster or more/less secure than just creating a separate list for the names. I do think it would be more readable if the list would get too long though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create an [abstract model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and use the clean method there and later inherit your models from that:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

BAD_WORDS = ['abc', 'def']

class TitleMixin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitleMixin, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
        if any(w in self.title for w in BAD_WORDS):
            raise ValidationError('Bad Title')
```

Now use the above abstract model to create new models and all have the same functionality for checking bad words in title:

```
class MyNewModel(TitleMixin):
    pass
```

Comment: Okay cool. Is there a particular reason the BAD_WORDS list isn't defined within the clean function?

Comment: No reason. BAD_WORDS might be used in some other abstract models or some where else so it is easy to import them if they are declared at global scope level. You can define them where ever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Hard coding into the clean function, and displaying to the user is the best means.  Test if any words are in the banned_words list, and show as error to user:

`Sorry, the following words are not allowed: foo, bar, foobar`